# Discover what JavaScript function was used to call a record_stats to the server

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to figure this out for quite a long time and I've been unsuccessful.

There's a game page ([www.trevorgames.com](http://www.trevorgames.com)) which records users stats and achievements (e.g. Soul Shift Game - http://www.tremorgames.com/playgame/7235/soul-shift.html). I want to understand which function is triggered to update the user stats in the server.

First of all I checked and it only records if you're logged in, so I made a dummy account for testing purposes (User:markwoods5000 Pass:12345) if someone want to help me out. While using the Chrome Dev Tools I was able to check that every time I finish a level in every game of this site it generates a new entry in the Network tab as it follows

```
curl "http://www.tremorgames.com/achievements/record_stats.php" -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=a5665001a2f52df60d7c670dabe3492a; tguserid=1224522; eccheck=1; uid=1224522; __utma=269348916.337017670.1426184538.1426392700.1426447408.15; __utmb=269348916.4.10.1426447408; __utmc=269348916; __utmz=269348916.1426188456.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not"%"20provided)" -H 
    "Origin: http://www.tremorgames.com" -H 
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H 
"Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H 
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: */*" -H 
    "Referer: http://www.tremorgames.com/games/files/1362598225_7235_SoulShift.swf" -H "X-Requested-With: ShockwaveFlash/17.0.0.134" -H 
    "Connection: keep-alive" --data 
    "StatValue=54&StatName=Stars"%"20Earned&Key=556f8db3f82c9613090b5d59cc715c4f&GameID=209&PlayerName=marcossilva"%"5F604" --compressed
```

I have several questions about this.
I want to know how the `Key=556f8db3f82c9613090b5d59cc715c4f` is calculated.
I want to know which function was called to update the status on the server (so I can possibly figure out how the key is calculated).
I want to know if the makePOSTRequest (code is below) could 've been used to update the info on the server.

```
function makePOSTRequest(url, parameters, SpanName) {
    http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
    http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {
    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
    try {
    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {}
    }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
    alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
    }  
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
    if (http_request.status == 200) {
    //alert(http_request.responseText);
    result = http_request.responseText;
    document.getElementById(SpanName).innerHTML = result;
    //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Ready'; 
    } else {
    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
    }
    };
    http_request.open('POST', url, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http_request.send(parameters);
  }
```

Comment: I'm sure they use a hashing algorithm to produce that and so prevent people from hacking their own stats: which sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: But even with a hashing algorithm the Key would have been generated on client side, right? But what is feed to the algorithm 'll remain a mistery because it's black-boxed, right?

Comment: If it is in the js that you load then no, it is not hidden, just obfuscated. I am sure you can step through the code in the debugger of your choice and see what is going on. I'm sure it will also take some time and require good javascript skills. So it will  not just be what is in the javascript that you require, they will have some sort of salt and key on the server to verify the key.